# convert class components to functional components in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, file-upload, react-functional-component

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to upload multiple images using expo-image-picker-multiple but I'm having an error with the code so I'm trying to convert the class component to functional components so I can easily deal with it since I'm more familiar with functional components.

```
export default class ImageBrowse extends Component {
    _getHeaderLoader = () => (
        <ActivityIndicator size='small' color={'#0580FF'} />
    );

    imagesCallback = (callback) => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        this.props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => this._getHeaderLoader()
        });
        callback.then(async (photos) => {
            const cPhotos = [];
            for (let photo of photos) {
                const pPhoto = await this._processImageAsync(photo.uri);
                cPhotos.push({
                    uri: pPhoto.uri,
                    name: photo.filename,
                    type: 'image/jpg'
                })
            }
            navigation.navigate('Main', { photos: cPhotos });
        })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    };



    async _processImageAsync(uri) {
        const file = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
            uri,
            [{ resize: { width: 1000 } }],
            { compress: 0.8, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.JPEG }
        );
        return file;
    };

    _renderDoneButton = (count, onSubmit) => {
        if (!count) return null;
        return <TouchableOpacity title={'Done'} onPress={onSubmit}>
            <Text onPress={onSubmit}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }

    updateHandler = (count, onSubmit) => {
        this.props.navigation.setOptions({
            title: `Selected ${count} files`,
            headerRight: () => this._renderDoneButton(count, onSubmit)
        });
    };

    renderSelectedComponent = (number) => (
        <View style={styles.countBadge}>
            <Text style={styles.countBadgeText}>{number}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    render() {
        const emptyStayComponent = <Text style={styles.emptyStay}>Empty =(</Text>;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.flex, styles.container]}>
                <ImageBrowser
                    max={4}
                    onChange={this.updateHandler}
                    callback={this.imagesCallback}
                    renderSelectedComponent={this.renderSelectedComponent}
                    emptyStayComponent={emptyStayComponent}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Also this is related to the above code:

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            photos: []
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { params } = this.props.route;
        if (params) {
            const { photos } = params;
            if (photos) this.setState({ photos });
            delete params.photos;
        }
    }

    renderImage(item, i) {
        return (
            <Image
                style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
                source={{ uri: item.uri }}
                key={i}
            />
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Button
                    title="Open image browser"
                    onPress={() => { navigate('ImageBrowser'); }}
                />
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.state.photos.map((item, i) => this.renderImage(item, i))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**The error is when I browse the gallery to select images nothing is showing:**

[image: Browse Screen]

**And this warning showing to me:**

[image: Warning]

**Also this is what i came up with when I tried to convert class to functional components:**

```
const PropertiesInfo = ({ navigation }) => {
const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([]);

const componentDidUpdate=()=> {
    const { params } = attachments.route;
    if (params) {
        const { attachments } = params
        if (attachments) setAttachments({ attachments })
        delete params.attachments
    }
};

const renderImage=(item, i) =>{
    return (
        <Image
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
            source={{ uri: item.uri }}
            key={i}
        />
    )
};

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Button
            title="Open image browser"
            onPress={() => { navigate('ImageBrowser'); }}
        />
        <ScrollView>
            {attachments.map((item, i) => renderImage(item, i))}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);

};

export default PropertiesInfo;
```

**And this also:**

```
const ImageBrowse=({ navigation })=>  {

_getHeaderLoader = () => (
    <ActivityIndicator size='small' color={'#0580FF'} />
);

imagesCallback = (callback) => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => _getHeaderLoader()
    });
    callback.then(async (attachments) => {
        const cPhotos = [];
        for (let photo of attachments) {
            const pPhoto = await _processImageAsync(photo.uri);
            cPhotos.push({
                uri: pPhoto.uri,
                name: photo.filename,
                type: 'image/jpg'
            })
        }
        navigation.navigate('Main', { attachments: cPhotos });
    })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};



const _processImageAsync = async (uri) => {
    const file = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
        uri,
        [{ resize: { width: 1000 } }],
        { compress: 0.8, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.JPEG }
    );
    return file;
};

_renderDoneButton = (count, onSubmit) => {
    if (!count) return null;
    return <TouchableOpacity title={'Done'} onPress={onSubmit}>
        <Text onPress={onSubmit}>Done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}

updateHandler = (count, onSubmit) => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        title: `Selected ${count} files`,
        headerRight: () => _renderDoneButton(count, onSubmit)
    });
};

renderSelectedComponent = (number) => (
    <View style={styles.countBadge}>
        <Text style={styles.countBadgeText}>{number}</Text>
    </View>
);


    const emptyStayComponent = <Text style={styles.emptyStay}>Empty =(</Text>;

    return (
        <View style={[styles.flex, styles.container]}>
            <ImageBrowser
                max={4}
                onChange={updateHandler}
                callback={imagesCallback}
                renderSelectedComponent={renderSelectedComponent}
                emptyStayComponent={emptyStayComponent}
            />
        </View>
    );



};

export default ImageBrowse;
```

Comment: Please add which error do you get, and what is the code for the functional component you ended up with.

Comment: @AlexBuznik I edited the post and added what you asked for please have a look.

Comment: Thanks. If you expect `const componentDidUpdate` to magically be called after render like in React.Component then it won't, please see `useEffect` hook. Anyway, that does not have to do with your error - did you try to do what the error explanation suggests?  Looks like you did not add and link the library that could request for the files permissions.